# Still I don't know how to use modifiers properly

Tags: modifiers

For example, a blueberry is blue fruit and if the fruit becomes yellow, is it called 'Yellow blueberry'? That is, 'yellow' is modifying 'blueberry'?

Comment: A blueberry is a species of fruit, and immature blueberries are green, so it's perfectly acceptable to refer to a "green blueberry" as meaning one that isn't ripe yet.

Comment: Yes: "yellow" is an adjective modifying the noun "blueberry".

Comment: Curiously, it turns out I completely agree with the assertion [*The color of **green** **black**berries is **red***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22The+color+of+green+blackberries+is+red%22) In that context, ***black*** simply identifies a particular *variety* of berry, and ***green*** means ***unripe***, so only ***red*** is used "literally" to identify a specific ***colour***.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In every compound noun the first noun functions as an adjective. School Student.
My brother - here my functions as possessive adjective.
Blueberry has many types it is not appropriate to say yellow blueberry; however, we can use the yellow blueberry.

Comment: 'It is not appropriate' means there's no yellow blueberry in reality but there could be imaginary yellow blueberry or yellow blueberry drawing?

Comment: Then it is a yellow blueberry drawing. Here yellow functions as an adjective.

Comment: That's incorrect: in "my brothers", "my" is a possessive **pronoun** functioning as a **determiner**. Also, "my brother" is not a compound noun, but a **noun phrase**, a  syntactic construction consisting of "brother" as head and "my" as determiner.

Comment: Hey there, My functions as an adjective in the above sentence. Mine is possessive pronoun. Try to expand your knowledge of English grammar.